# Why this ffmpeg mp4/mkv/wmv/flv/avi to webm command line with cuda is as slow as with CPU?

Tags: ffmpeg, vorbis, vp9

im playing with my video files, I want to convert them from mp4, mkv, wmv, avi, flv, mov... to webm.

So I have written this:

```
for file in *
    do   
if [ -f "$file" ]
    then     filename="${file%.*}"
    ../ffmpeg -hwaccel nvdec -hwaccel_device 0 -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i "$file" -c:v vp9 -b:v 0 -crf 31 -c:a libvorbis "$filename".webm
fi
done
```

As shown, I have compiler my own ffmpeg binary, with those options:

```
./configure --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-cuda-nvcc --enable-libvpx --enable-vaapi --enable-libvorbis  --enable-libnpp --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64
```

It works, but, with CPU I got speed 0,1x and with cuda... almost the same.

My CPU?   11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-11800H

My GPU?   GeForce RTX™ 3060 mobile

Filesize? 300-3000mb (same speed with any)

Is there anything I could do? (I also tried vp9_vaapi, getting

```
Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'Parsed_null_0' and the filter 'auto_scale_0'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Function not implemented
```

Any clue? Or do I have to give up?

Thanks

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_NVENC), NVENC supports H.264 and H.265 codecs but not VP9 codec. `-hwaccel nvdec` applies only the decoder. `-c:v vp9` uses the CPU for encoding. `vp9_vaapi` (or `vp9_qsv`) may use Intel Quick Sync encoder, but you should put it after the `-i`. Try `ffmpeg -i "$file" -c:v vp9_vaapi -b:v 0 -crf 31 -c:a libvorbis "$filename".webm`. It may not work due to Linux drivers issues.

Comment: Hi, i got [vost#0:0/vp9_vaapi @ 0x56240f5db9c0] Finishing stream without any data written to it.
Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'Parsed_null_0' and the filter 'auto_scale_0'
[vost#0:0/vp9_vaapi @ 0x56240f5db9c0] Error configuring filter graph
Exiting normally, received signal 2. I dont know what it means...

Comment: What is the video codec of the input?

Comment: Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> vp9 (vp9_vaapi))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> vorbis (libvorbis))

Comment: Try `ffmpeg -c:v h264_vaapi -i "$file" -c:v vp9_vaapi -b:v 0 -crf 31 -c:a libvorbis "$filename".webm`

Comment: I got Unknown decoder 'h264_vaapi'
which flag i need to add to ./configure?

Comment: I am using Windows (there is no VAAPI). I guess h264_vaapi is an encoder. Last try: `ffmpeg -c:v h264_qsv -i "$file" -c:v vp9_qsv -b:v 0 -crf 31 -c:a libvorbis "$filename".webm`

Comment: Unknown decoder 'h264_qsv'
Maybe in winfows could I have better performance?

Comment: I don't know, I would like to think that in Intel Gen 11 using Quick Sync is faster compared to CPU encoding.

Comment: welll then, last question... my target is to get a video that could be played while is still downloaded... my first option was webm... but its very slow... mp4 avi and mkv are discarded because they dont let play the file until is complete... any options? aside ts or mpd

Comment: I don't know... is it really working with WebM? In case it does, you may try FLV with H.264 codec, or TS (mpeg-ts) with H.264 or H.265.

Comment: Yes its working with webm, i will give a try to that options, thanks

Comment: it worked with h264 and .ts

Answer (score 1):

Well, after some tests, the bests results were obtained using

```
-c:v libvpx-vp9 -cpu-used 8 -deadline realtime
```

speed increased from 0,05x to 1,12x slow, but, good enough.

Quality is good for me.